# Standard error computed by MATLAB multcompare?

Tags: matlab

Here is my toy data

```
y = [1; 1; 2; 6; 7; 3];
```

and their group information is as follows

```
grp = ['a'; 'b'; 'b'; 'a'; 'c'; 'c'];
```

I perform the one-way ANOVA on it.

```
[~, ~, stats] = anova1(y, grp, 'off');
```

Then, I do a pairwise comparison with [multcompare](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/multcompare.html)

```
[c, m, ~, gnames] = multcompare(stats);
```

Strangely, the group standard errors are the same!

```
disp('Mean and standard errors:');
disp([gnames num2cell(m)]);

Mean and standard errors:
    'a'    [3.5]    [1.87082869338697]
    'b'    [1.5]    [1.87082869338697]
    'c'    [  5]    [1.87082869338697]
```

How can this be possible?

---

I tried to compute standard errors manually myself. Surprisingly,

```
>> std(y(grp=='a'))/sqrt(sum(grp=='a'))

ans =

                       2.5

>> std(y(grp=='b'))/sqrt(sum(grp=='b'))

ans =

                       0.5

>> std(y(grp=='c'))/sqrt(sum(grp=='c'))

ans =

     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the comparisons are based on using a common estimate of $\sigma^2$, computed from the residuals $s^2=\frac{1}{n-k}\sum_{j=1}^k\sum_{i=1}{n_j}(x_{ij}-\bar{x}_{.j})^2$, exactly as is done in ANOVA.

Then, because your sample sizes are all identical, the estimated standard error of each group mean will necessarily be the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir! I still cannot wrap my head around it. Could you please elaborate a bit? Like, why is my way of computing the standard error incorrect? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since your way was *not* based on a common estimate of $\sigma^2$, clearly the result will be different from a calculation that *is*. That doesn't automatically make it incorrect, but it won't correspond to what standard ANOVA does.

Comment: I see. So in the case where I need to show the means (SE) for each group and pairwise comparisons, should I show the SE by my way or the one by the comment estimate? For example, [this table](http://postimg.org/image/pa2yuqcvb/). Thanks a lot!

Comment: If you're presenting summary statistics for a sample, you do exactly that. It doesn't relate to the calculations you're asking about here.

Comment: well, so I should compute the SE with SD/sqrt(N). Then what does the SE by ANOVA tell us?

Comment: Comments are not a chat forum; we're no longer clarifying your question nor my answer -- you're simply posing a sequence of new questions with no clear end in sight. This is not a forum for one-on-one tutorials.